# How to structure a downloadable content package that includes paragraphs?

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures

I am making a flash cards app. Each flash card has the following
- a topic
- a question
- an answer

The answer can be multiple paragraphs like a short article.

For example:
topic: nutrition
question: What is paleo?
answer: Paleo is a low carb diet. \n
It relies on specific meats and vegetables as the staple of the diet. You cannot eat bread on paleo.

CSV doesn't seem like an option unless I sub out the \n for something like ~~

The paragraph may have quotes in it as well. I would like to be able to download a pack of flashcards for offline use so just pulling from a database wouldn't be ideal for this.

Is there a good format/structure I can use to bundle up a pack of flashcards for easy download/parsing/saving on the local system?

Comment: XML? HTML? Property list? SQLite? Just about anything _other_ than CSV would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could represent your data as follows:

```
struct Card: Codable {
    let topic: String
    let question: String
    let answer: String
}
```

Then if you have an array `let card = [Card]` you can convert to JSON using a `JSONEncoder` and from JSON to `Card` using `JSONDecoder`

```
let cards = [Card(topic: "Nutrition", question: "What is paleo?", answer: "Paleo is a low carb diet.\nIt relies on specific meats and vegetables as the staple of the diet. You cannot eat bread on paleo.")]

let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(cards)

let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

print(string)

// [{"topic":"Nutrition","question":"What is paleo?","answer":"Paleo is a low carb diet.\nIt relies on specific meats and vegetables as the staple of the diet. You cannot eat bread on paleo."}]

let newCards = try JSONDecoder().decode([Card].self, from: data)
```